# C# application getting disconnected from local api, usure how to reconnect without restarting the program

Tags: c#, api, reconnect

Hi everyone I'm new to c# and I've done my first 2 weeks in this language, so my knowlege is pretty basic.

I'm playing with an app that connects to a client (League of legends client) and uses varius methods to send and get info (Get, Post, Put and Delete).

**What the program does:**

1. Once the app is started there's a public class that is called when the form is loaded.

`public LCU lcu = new LCU();` (I'll add the code of LCU down below) <-- this strats the connection

2. I can send as many requests as I want, here's a working example:

`var request = await lcu.http_client.DeleteAsync(lcu.baseURL + "/lol-lobby/v2/lobby").ConfigureAwait(true);`

My problem is that when I make too many requests (every 2 seconds or below), the app is disconnected from the client/api and to fix that I would need a task that reconnects.

Now I'm not sure how to do that, I've tried adding `LCU lcu = new LCU();` inside a timer, but that didn't work.

I would love to know why it didn't work and if you have some suggestions on how to do it, I'll be happy to know.

Thank you!!

**LCU.cs** (not the main form)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LeaguePW5
{
    public class LCU
    {
        public string address { get; set; }
        public int port { get; set; }
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
        public string protocol { get; set; }
        public string process_name { get; set; }
        public int process_id { get; set; }
        public string baseURL => string.Format("{0}://{1}:{2}", this.protocol, this.address, this.port);
        public LCU()
        {
            Process[] process = Process.GetProcessesByName("LeagueClientUx");
            if (process.Length != 0)
            {
                string lockFile;
                using (FileStream stream = File.Open(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(process[0].MainModule.FileName), "lockfile"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                {
                    lockFile = new StreamReader(stream).ReadToEnd();
                }
                string[] parameters = lockFile.Split(new string[] { ":" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                this.username = "riot";
                this.address = "127.0.0.1";
                this.process_name = parameters[0];
                this.process_id = Convert.ToInt32(parameters[1]);
                this.port = Convert.ToInt32(parameters[2]);
                this.password = parameters[3];
                this.protocol = parameters[4];
            }

        }
        public HttpClient http_client
        {
            get
            {
                HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
                httpClientHandler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
                httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = ((HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage, X509Certificate2 cert, X509Chain cetChain, SslPolicyErrors policyErrors) => true);
                return new HttpClient(httpClientHandler)
                {
                    DefaultRequestHeaders =
                    {
                        Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("riot:" + this.password)))
                    }
                };
            }
            set
            {
            }
        }



    }
}
```

**P.S.** If you need the full code, I'll be happy to share it

Comment: Add a dispose method to the LCU class.

Comment: Http connections aren't persistent, each request would create a new connection unless the header "connection" is not set to "close". Sometimes the connection pooling mechanism could cause problems if you are behind a router or firewall, in those cases the best you can do is to ensure that each request is executed in a new connection, for that add "ConnectionClose = true" in the client `DefaultRequestHeaders`

Answer (score 2):

You have a mistake in `http_client` initialization. It returns new instance every time you're making the request.

Per [`HttpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8) documentation:

> `// HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once per application, rather than per-use`.

Try this fix and you'll not be disconnected. (in addition I've applied naming policy for property, widely used by Microsoft in .NET)

```csharp
private HttpClient _httpClient; // backing field
public HttpClient HttpClient
{
    get
    {
        if (_httpClient == null) // create new instance only if still not created
        {
            HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
            httpClientHandler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
            httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = ((HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage, X509Certificate2 cert, X509Chain cetChain, SslPolicyErrors policyErrors) => true);
            _httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler)
            {
                DefaultRequestHeaders =
                {
                    Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("riot:" + this.password)))
                }
            };
        }
        return _httpClient;
    }
}
```

And usage

```
await lcu.HttpClient.DeleteAsync(lcu.baseURL + "/lol-lobby/v2/lobby").ConfigureAwait(false);
```

`ConfigureAwait(true)` is default. Use `false` or not use `ConfigureAwait` to avoid a redundant overhead.

Additionally you may derive `LCU` class from `IDisposable` and [implement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose) the interface because `HttpClient` is `IDisposable`. And call `HttpClient.Dispose()` in the disposing method. But it makes sense only if you create `new LCU()` class multiple times.

Comment: Thank you very much for the super answer! It's a little bit complicated but I'll be looking into it really soon.

@Gusman 's answer works super well

Comment: @Germ with my fix you may remove `ConnectionClose = true` and possibly you'll get a performance boost. Because `HttpClient` will reuse already open existing TCP connections instead of establishing new ones for each request.